# sp_send_dbmail : send email if specific variable selected

Tags: sql, email, stored-procedures

I am currently having an issue in SQL where I have a website that should fire an email if a specific Category is selected. At the moment it will fire regardless of the Category selected.

```
 IF @NotesCategory = 14

     EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

     @profile_name = 'profilename',
     @from_address = @NotesSenderEmail,
     @reply_to     = @NotesSenderEmail,
     @recipients   = @Email,
     @subject      = 'subject',
     @body         = @mybody,
     @body_format  = 'HTML',
     @importance   = 'High'

END
```

...and for some reason  it will fire regards of if Notes Category is 14 or not.

Any advice is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Try `IF @NotesCategory = 14 BEGIN ... END ... END`.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `BEGIN`

```
IF @NotesCategory = 14
    BEGIN
         EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

         @profile_name = 'profilename',
         @from_address = @NotesSenderEmail,
         @reply_to     = @NotesSenderEmail,
         @recipients   = @Email,
         @subject      = 'subject',
         @body         = @mybody,
         @body_format  = 'HTML',
         @importance   = 'High'

    END
```